# Adding a Jekyll site to my existing gulp project?

Tags: gulp, jekyll, netlify

I have an existing gulp project (my marketing site) hosted via Netlify and I'd like to add a Jekyll site to this project.

It would live in a blog folder so that the site points to mymarketingsite.com/blog

Whenever I drop the Jekyll project in the /blog directory nothing seems to be picked up. My assumption is that I have to somehow edit the gulpfile to point to and build the project?

I'm a product designer by day, so I apologize for my lack of understanding here -- any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach of having 2 sites hosted on the one domain on **Netlify** that might be a better option for you than mixing the sites together into one project and having to go through a lot of work to reconfigure your build tasks in gulp. There have been some articles about this that speak to it well.

- Keep your marketing site (gulp) in it's own repository.
- Keep your Jekyll site in it's own repository.
- Deploy the Jekyll site to a separate site on Netlify (i.e. your-jekyll-site.netlify.com).
- Have the main site (your marketing site) [configure a proxy](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) to the `/blog` path pointing to the Jekyll site

`_redirects` in the root of the marketing site:

```
/blog/*  https://your-jekyll-site.netlify.com/:splat  200
```

### Advantages

- Each site can be configured and worked on separately
- At any time, you can make them their own domain with little effort
- Less work than having to reconfigure work you have already done
- You can change your blog site to another SSG later with no changes to your marketing site

**Note:** Make sure your Jekyll site has been configured for the `/blog` path as the root

Comment: This sounds like the perfect solution! Thank you!

I've implemented all of the steps, though I'm a little confused about what you mean when you say "Make sure your Jekyll site has been configured for the /blog path as the root"? 

Are you referring to the _config.yml file? Or the publish directory in Netlify?

Comment: Just referring to the `baseurl` in your build of the Jekyll site.